# Showing college credit earned during high school on resume?

Tags: resume, applications, internship, student

I am a college sophomore applying for internships. During my senior year of high school, I attended classes at a college full-time as part of my school's early college program. These credits transferred to my current college, and I currently have close to the same number of credits from both universities. How should I indicate these credits on my resumé, if at all?

Comment: Maybe just note your expected graduation date if it's sooner because of the credits earned in high school.

Comment: Does your transcript from your current college include them as transfer credits? I know my transcript listed my AP credits.

Comment: Definitely mention it in your cover letter.

Comment: For the first college (while you were in high school), am I correct that you weren't in a degree program?  Were you in a program that had any sort of name, or -- from the college's point of view -- were you just somebody taking some classes and then moving on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The yardstick you should use is "Is the information I am including in my resume relevant to the prospective employer who reads my resume? If so, in what way? What point that's relevant am I trying to make by including this information for them to read?"

If you are going for a white collar job that requires a certain amount of brainpower, a prospective employer would appreciate your info that you are making unusually good progress in your university education as evidence that you have brainpower. But they would not appreciate the minutiae of your university course credit history.

Answer (score 1):

I've listed them like:

```
 Some Early Entry College 20xx-20yy
 Some Primary College     20yy-20zz
```

Without making note of the early entry portion. Majors are good, grades are good to list if the grades are good. I've found that my early entry to college is not universally regarded as a good thing by employers.